# Stopping the output of a for cycle in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, output

I'm facing an issue with this simple Fibonacci number generator program:

```
function f = fibonr(n)
f(1) = 1; 
f(2) = 1;
    for i = 3:n
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2);
    end

end
```

If I want to display only the n-th number of the sequence, what adjustments should I make?

Comment: Once the for-loop is completed (after n iterations) the nth number will be the last one stored in `f` right? You can then display `f(end)` after the `end` statement of the loop. Is it what you mean?

Comment: I did as you' ve said, but in this case I get two outputs: the first one with the last number stored, and the answer of the program with the whole vector of numbers

Answer (score 2):

```
function f = fibonr(n)
f = zeros(n,1); %//initialise the output array
f(1,1) = 1;
f(2,1) = 1;
for ii = 3:n
    f(ii,1) = f(ii-1,1) + f(ii-2,1);
end
%//create a string with text and variables
str = sprintf('The %d th number in the Fibonacci sequence is %d',n,f(ii,1));
disp(str) %//display your output.
end
```

first up: [*don't use `i` as a variable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). Secondly, I switched to using column vectors, since MATLAB processes them faster, as well as I initialised the array, which is way faster (hence the shiny orange wiggles below your `f(i)=` line).

Call your function:

```
output = fibonr(10);
The 10 th number in the Fibonacci sequence is 55
```

If you use e.g. `n=20` and still want the 10th argument just call `output(10)`

Comment: May you explain me what the statement zeros(n,1) means?

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I have tried using your code, but what I get is an infinite list of the nth number

Comment: Just use the function as presented and the code below "call your function" in your command window.

Comment: Yes, but I want that the program gives me back immediately the output, without further interaction... Is this possible?

Comment: Also, don't write `for ii=3:inf`;)

Comment: Sorry, probably I'm being obnoxious, but is there any way to suppress the output given by ans? I want the program to display only the nth number!

Comment: Yes, there is, use the semicolon like I showed you in the answer. Please *read* the answer carefully and *copy the code exactly*

Comment: But I've put the semicolon after f(ii)=f(ii-1,1) + f(ii-2,1); it just doesn't suppress the output! I don't know why it happens... I'm using matlab 2012 anyway

Comment: Because you are calling your function like `fibonr(10)` and not like I showed you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the specified output right away you can use `nargin`. This code will give you all of the sequence if you call `fibonr(n)`, or you can specify a vector to get the fibonacy numbers at said positions. If you are interested in both, your specified output and all the numbers, you can call the function with:
`[output, fibnumbers] = fibonr(n,v);`

```
function [output,f] = fibonr(n,v)
f(1) = 1; 
f(2) = 1;
    for i = 3:n
    f(i) = f(i-1) + f(i-2);
    end

 if nargin() > 1
     output = f(v);
 else
     output = f;
end
```